# Isotherm process confusion

Tags: thermodynamics

In our lectures we have the two following expressions about the relation between heat and temperature:

$dQ= C \cdot dT$ where C is the heat capacity.

We also have the following (from the 2nd thermodynamic law):

dQ=TdS.

Now if we are observing an isotherm process, then for the above equation dQ is zero and below we cannot say anything, unless the entropie is constant (how can we tell?)

The same goes when we have an adiabatic process, for example an adiabatic expansion. Since no heat is given to the system which is expanding, the only way for this to occur is for the system to lose energy (since it's working on the enviroment), which translates temperature reduction. But if we look at the above equations the first gives us dQ=/=0 and the 2nd one gives dQ=0.

Comment: If it is an ideal gas, the $$\Delta U=C_v\Delta T=Q-W$$.  Your first equation is correct only under certain specific conditions, and your second equation is correct only if the process is reversible and at constant temperature.

Comment: also, for an isothermal expansion, $Q\neq0$ by the first law of thermodynamics

Answer (score -1):

In the case of the isothermal process, the heat absorbed or released is not zero. This is because work is done in an isothermal process. The equation $Q=Cdt$ is valid only for the case, where no work is done. Thus, it cannot be used here.

Moreover, think about a phase transition, for example, the melting of ice into water. Does the temperature change? No, right, and yet latent heat is absorbed. This is an example, where $dt=0$ but heat absorbed is non-zero.

Use the same logic for adiabatic processes. The first equation simply doesn't apply here either, as work is done during an adiabatic process.

Always use the equation $Tds$ or $C_pdT$ ( For isobaric processes )